# How to get maximum repeating value in last week

Tags: mysql

I have a table `property_viewers` with 3 fields; id, property_id, date. I need to find maximum property_id repeating in last week. How shall i proceed...

Comment: maximum property_id, or maximum repeats?

Comment: last week, as last 7 days or monday to sunday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *, count(1)  from property_viewers where DATEDIFF(date, DATE(now()))<8 group by property_id order by count(1) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select property_id, count(property_id)  from property_viewers 
where `date` between 'weekSTartDate' and 'weekEndDate' 
group by property_id order by count(property_id) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT property_id
FROM property_viewers
WHERE date BETWEEN 
    CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL (7+WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE())) DAY AND   //Monday last week
    CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL (1+WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE())) DAY       //Sunday last week
GROUP BY property_id
ORDER BY COUNT(property_id) DESC
```